# moving from publicly accessible rds database to using bastion ec2 instance to connect to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, relational-database

If one has a publicly accessible rds database on aws, and wants to instead use a bastion ec2 instance to access and perform database functions (anyone on the internet should be able to use the app and perform database functions in accordance with the features provided by the app), how should one go about performing this shift? I have tried searching the internet but often I get loads of information with terminology that isn't entirely easy to digest. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Again, I want the general public to be able to use and access the app's provided db functions, but not have them be able to access the database directly.

Comment: You should be able to Modify the database and set `Publicly Accessible = No`. It will then only be accessible from within the VPC. Is there any other specific problem you are having?

Comment: if I do that, and I have a sign up function in my app (which involves db queries), would that mean people won't be able to sign up (due to the accessibility being turned off, and thus they won't be able to invoke these db functions)?

Comment: The architecture should be: `users -> app -> database` Your users should not have any access to the database. They will interact with your app, which can talk to the database.

Comment: would that mean there is no need for a bastion host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical 3-tier architecture is:

- A **Load Balancer** across public subnets, which sends traffic to...
- Multiple **Amazon EC2 instances** in private subnets, preferable provisioned through Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling, which can scale based on demand and can also replace failed instances, which are all talking to...
- A **Database** in a private subnet, preferably in Multi-AZ mode, which means that a failure in the database or in an Availability Zone will not lose any data

However, your application may not require this much infrastructure. For low-usage applications, you could just use:

- An Amazon EC2 instance as your **application server** running in a public subnet
- An Amazon RDS database in a private subnet, with a security group configured to permit access from the Amazon EC2 instance

Users would connect to your application server. The application server would connect to the database. Users would have no direct access to the database.

However, ***YOU* might require access to the database** for administration and testing purposes. Since the database is in a private subnet, it is not reachable from the Internet. To provide *you* with access, you could launch another Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet, with a security group configured to permit *you* to access the instance. This instance "sticks out" on the Internet, and is thus called a **Bastion server** (named after the part of a castle wall that *sticks out* to allow archers to fire on invaders climbing the caste wall).

You can use **port forwarding** to connect to the Bastion server and then through to the database. For example:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@BASTION-IP -L 3306:DATABASE-DNS-NAME:3306
```

This configures the SSH connection to forward `localhost:3306` to port 3306 on the named database server. This allows your local machine to talk to the database via the Bastion server.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer - appreciate it. When I first created my aws account, it seems I've already got a VPC with 3 subnets - would I still stick to these or create new ones?

Comment: The "proper" answer is that you should create the VPC architecture that your application(s) need. The default VPC is provided so that people can start using services without having to first learn about VPCs. However, now that you are doing "real" work, then you should definitely consider what your network should look like. If you are working in a company, then there are probably networking people who will design and manage this side of the system. If you are doing a one-man project, then it doesn't matter as much. It is probably "better" to create a new VPC and relaunch your resources in it.

Comment: it's a one man project so if it's alright I'll stick to what I currently have. My application server ec2 instance is currently in one subnet so I'm assuming I'll have to change that subnet to public and add a bastion host in it as well?

As for the RDS it's apparently in all 3 subnets and the heading 'subnet group' is listed as default. Would I have to somehow put it in just one subnet and change it to private?

Comment: A Subnet Group tells the Amazon RDS database where it _can_ go, but it normally lives in only one of them unless you have configured Multi-AZ or added Read Replicas.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create private subnets for this and update DBsubnet groups accordingly with private subnets only. Moreover in DB security group add bastion and app instances security group as source for db port.

Like if you're using mysql engine, allow 3306 for target instances secuirty group id's.

Comment: just to clarify, would the rds and bastion host be in the private subnet, and the ec2 instance be in the public subnet?

Comment: RDS would be in private, bastion host would be public, if application instances are behind a load balancer then it should be in private subnet else application also in public subnet.